# How do I use sinon.js to mock/spy object mentioned inside the javascript function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

How do I use sinon.js to mock/spy object mentioned inside the javascript function?
The mentioned object makes a method call as well and I need to test if the method is called by that object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a Million in advance!

Awaiting any response.

```
var ABCClient = require('ABCClient');
var connect = function(){
  var client;
  client = new ABCClient(); //instantiating object

  client.on('some parameter'); // Test if the `on` event is called.
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular case you want to handle? (ie. code sample). If it's only an object to local scope of that function, then it would be pretty difficult to do that. But a code sample would be great start for me to come up with a suggestion. @user3785790

Comment: @lwang135 Thanks for Replying back. The object is local to the scope of the function. Adding a Sample snippet of the code above in my question.
Thanks to take a look into that.
Awaiting any response.

Comment: `client` is only accessible within the anonymous function assigned to `connect`. You need to expose that object publicly to spy on it, e.g. have it as the return value of calling `connect()`.

Comment: @user2943490 thanks for replying. I'm afraid to do the changes inside the code. Is there any other way around to snoop inside the code using sinon and spy on the var client and its method .on in a test case?

Comment: @user2943490: what you said i think it might be right as returning that object would allow to spy on it. But is there any other way around apart from doing that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your mock. This is fairly straight forward once you step back and think about it. You are creating an instance of a class. Simply do this:

```
var ABCClient = require('ABCClient');

describe('test', function() {
  it('some test', function() {
     var stub = sinon.stub(ABCClient.prototype, 'on').yields('return object');
     assert.ok(stub.calledWith('Parameter'));
     ABCClient.prototype.on.restore();
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can just use `spy` over `stub` if you just want to spy on it without changing behaviour.

In this sample, you are stubbing the `prototype` such that all the instances will have that property/method stubbed. Thus, you will be able to access the object. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @Iwang135: Thats Brilliant. I'll try what you have mentioned and give you a shout.
Thanks for the code sample. I'm new to this kinda testing. 
I'll try this out and let you know.
Cheers.

Comment: @Harsh Actually, I was too quick at typing. There are couple things to do (i'll update the answer). 1. use `spy` if you want to maintain existing functionality, or use `stub` if you want to stub it, but make sure you return/yield something. 2. Make sure you `restore` it after the test.

Comment: @Iwang135: Sorry buddy for late reply, I was on holiday I didn't check it. I'll check it today at the office reply here. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Harsh Hey did that solve your problem. If it did, it'd be great if you can mark it, or else I can provide a bit more help :)

Comment: @Iwang135 : hey Buddy, thanks it did. Sorry i had no chance to check it any sooner. But i did check it lately and it did work. Thanks buddy ;)